# Does Hero's Feast make a party immune to the 9th level spell Weird?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The text of *Weird* seems to imply that the frightened condition is a prerequisite for the target to take damage. *Hero's Feast* makes a party immune to the frightened condition.  Would this mean that *Weird* would have no effect, i.e. PCs under *Hero's Feast*'s effect would not take damage?

Comment: I found a question (that I also answered) that I think is a duplicate. Does that seem like an appropriate dupe closure to you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Yes, *Hero’s Feast* makes you immune to *Weird*.

*Weird* says:

> At the end of each of *the frightened creature's* turns, it must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or take 4d10 psychic damage.

Since *hero’s feast* makes you immune to frightened, you cannot be “the frightened creature”, and only “the frightened creature” takes the damage from *weird*.

Comment: Thanks! What an underwhelming 9th level spell

Comment: @Trekkie Yeah, I have always been confused by this one. I have house ruled before that *weird* was 6th level and let one of my players use it that way, and it felt about right.